# Comparing 2 dimentional arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
String[][] Array1= {{"A","welcome","S"},
                   {"B","welcome","S"}, 
                   {"C","foodmart","L"}, 
                   {"D","welcome","S"},
                   {"E","publix","M"},};


String[][] Array2= {{"A","welcome","S"},
                    {"L","welcome","S"}, 
                    {"F","foodmart","L"}, 
                    {"D","welcome","S"},
                    {"B","welcome","S"},};
```

I want to compare the two arrays with 1st value i.e Array1[0][0] with Array2[0][0] and then add the value in the new array if the value is in both arrays if not dont add it in the new array.

Expected Output of the New Array After Comparision.

```
String[][] Array3 ={{"A","welcome","S"},
                   {"D","welcome","S"},
                   {"B","welcome","S"},};
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to compute what is essentially the intersection of two sets. Take a look at that.

Comment: Yeah I just need the intersection of the two arrays.

Comment: My point was that your arrays are the sets here. So if you figure out how to compute a set intersection you should be able to translate that to Java arrays.

Comment: Use collections instead of arrays and you get the necessary algorithm for calculating the intersection "for free". Switch to a list of lists of strings `List<List<String>>` and store the data in there instead. You can use the [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) method for "calculating" the intersection

Comment: Sorry, I thought they were arrays. I don't want to convert them into arrays just need the intersection of two sets in a new set.

Comment: Yes they are arrays at the moment. I am suggesting that you use lists instead of arrays so you can easily create an intersection by calling the `retainAll` method on one of those lists

Comment: Yeah got it  @tiguchi thanks for the suggestion but in my current project the 2 arrays are used in so many places so I cant change them.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and indicate where you are having problems. StackOverflow is not a code writing service - if you don't have code yet, you first need to make your own attempt.

Comment: Should B,publix,M be in the output?  The first array has B,welcome,S.  These don't appear to be duplicates.  And if they are duplicates then how does the second array value get chosen for the output?

Comment: Is there a specific rule for deciding ties?  Both `Array1` and `Array2` have a line with "B" as the [0] element, `Array3` ended up with the `{"B", "Publix", "M"}` line from `Array2` rather than the `{"B", "Welcome", "5"}` line from `Array1`.   Was it intentionally the one way instead of the other, or just a coincidence?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Sorry Updated the values.

Comment: I just want to tell you: it is convention(in java) that variables start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Just move to Scala ;): `a intersect b` done. Example: `val a = List(List("A","welcome","S"),
List("B","welcome","S"), 
List("C","foodmart","L"), 
List("D","welcome","S"),
List("E","publix","M"));

val b = List(List("A","welcome","S"),
List("L","welcome","S"), 
List("F","foodmart","L"), 
List("D","welcome","S"),
List("B","welcome","S"));


a intersect b; // gives:

List(List(A, welcome, S), List(B, welcome, S), List(D, welcome, S));`  Semicolons for readability here only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are not == just because the elements in the arrays are the same.  So it is necessary write special compare logic rather than using the collection method retainAll.

Using LinkedHashSet instances for the sets removes duplicates and keeps the set in the same order as the original arrays.

Here are two ways to make this work.  I prefer the second way if you are using java 11+.

Using java prior to java 1.8.

```
    Set<String[]> set1 = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Array1));
    Set<String[]> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Array2));
    Set<String[]> set3 = new LinkedHashSet<String[]>();

    Iterator<String[]> it1 = set1.iterator();
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        String[] element1 = it1.next();
        Iterator<String[]> it2 = set2.iterator();
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            String[] element2 = it2.next();
            if (element1[0].equals(element2[0])
                  && element1[1].equals(element2[1])
                  && element1[2].equals(element2[2])) {
                set3.add(element1);
            }
        }
    }
    set3.toArray(new String[][]{});
```

And if you are using java 11+ then you can use streams and the var keyword to make things much more readable.

```
    var set1 = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Array1));
    var set2 = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(Array2));
    var set3 = new LinkedHashSet<String[]>();

    set1.forEach(element1 ->
                   set2.stream()
                     .filter(element2 ->
                               element1[0].equals(element2[0])
                                 && element1[1].equals(element2[1])
                                 && element1[2].equals(element2[2]))
                     .findFirst()
                     .ifPresent(element2 -> set3.add(element1)));

    set3.toArray(new String[][]{});
```